# Image Pixel Intensity and Measure of Colourfulness in Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, euclidean-distance

I want to measure the average pixel intensity and measure of colourfulness of a image. For this i'm following this approach (kindly let me know if there's any alternative approach for the same):

a) Calculate Average Pixel Intensity:

```
im = Image.open('images-16.jpeg')
stat = ImageStat.Stat(im)
r,g,b = stat.mean
mean = sqrt(0.241* (r ** 2) + 0.691* (g ** 2) + 0.068* (b ** 2))
print(mean)
```

b) To measure colourfulness:

- Dividing color space into 64 cubic blocks with four equal partitions along each dimension

  ```
  w,h=im.size    
  bw,bh = 8, 8 #block size
  img = np.array(im)
  sz = img.itemsize
  shape = (h-bh+1, w-bw+1, bh, bw)
  strides = (w*sz, sz, w*sz, sz) 
  blocks = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(img, shape=shape, strides=strides)
  print (blocks[1,1])
  ```
- Calculate Euclidean distances between the geometric centers C*i* of each cube *i*
  `Not able to compute (say d(a,b)=rgb(Ca)-rgb(Cb))`
- **Distribution D1** is generated as the color distribution of a hypothetical image such that for each of 64 sample points, the frequency is 1/64 -

  `pixels = im.load()
  all_pixels = []
  for x in range(218): #put your block width size
  for y in range(218): #your block heigh size
      cpixel = pixels[x, y] 
      all_pixels.append(cpixel)`
- **Distribution D2** is computed from the given image by finding the frequency of occurrence of color within each of the 64 cubes `How can i do this?`
- Calculate `Earth Mover's Distance: (D1,D2,d(a,b))` - d(a,b) is calculated above

Is this the right way to do it? Any supporting documents to achieve this? Any help with the code is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: To start with, I would combine the r,g,b into a brightness for each pixel *before* calculating the mean. Use the proper gamma of `**2.2` and `**(1/2.2)` instead of `**2` and `sqrt`. And be sure to divide those pixel values by 255 first.

Comment: @MarkRansom ok sure will try that..and for measuring colourfulness?

Comment: Sorry, if I had advice for colourfulness I would have left a proper answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom np, ty for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You will need pyemd library.

```
from pyemd import emd
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import skimage.color

im = Image.open("t4.jpg")
pix = im.load()

h1 = [1.0/64] * 64
h2 = [0.0] * 64
hist1 = np.array(h1)

w,h = im.size

for x in xrange(w):
    for y in xrange(h):
        cbin = pix[x,y][0]/64*16 + pix[x,y][1]/64*4 + pix[x,y][2]/64
        h2[cbin]+=1
hist2 = np.array(h2)/w/h

# compute center of cubes

c = np.zeros((64,3))
for i in xrange(64):
    b = (i%4) * 64 + 32
    g = (i%16/4) * 64 + 32
    r = (i/16) * 64 + 32
    c[i]=(r,g,b)

c_luv = skimage.color.rgb2luv(c.reshape(8,8,3)).reshape(64,3)

d = np.zeros((64,64))

for x in xrange(64):
    d[x,x]=0
    for y in xrange(x):
        dist = np.sqrt( np.square(c_luv[x,0]-c_luv[y,0]) + 
                   np.square(c_luv[x,1]-c_luv[y,1]) + 
                   np.square(c_luv[x,2]-c_luv[y,2]))
        d[x,y] = dist
        d[y,x] = dist


colorfullness = emd(hist1, hist2, d)

print colorfullness
```

Comment: This looks nice and similar to the implementation I am trying to reproduce but when trying it the colorfulness of a colorful image is lower than the one is not so there might be something wrong ?